# How to transform sql query into Query Builder Laravel way?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need to convert this query into Laravel query builder or ORM

```
SET @start_date = '2020-11-01';
SET @end_date = '2020-11-08';
SET @duration = CONVERT(@end_date, DATE) - CONVERT(@start_date, DATE);

SELECT item_id, days
FROM (
SELECT item_id, sum(end_date - start_date) AS days 
FROM schedule WHERE start_date >= @start_date AND end_date <= @end_date 
GROUP BY item_id) AS virtual
WHERE days = @duration;
```

(i use Laravel 8)

i could not find similar example I could analize and try by myself :(

i try this :

```
$res = DB::table('schedule')
    ->select('schedule.item_id' , DB::raw("SUM(schedule.end_date - schedule.start_date) as days"))
    ->where('start_date', '>=', $start_date)
    ->where('end_date', '<=', $end_date)
    ->groupBy('item_id')
    ->where('days', '=', $duration)
    ->get();
```

but i get error :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'days' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: If you change `where` to `having` it might work. `WHERE` works on each column so aggregate values (such as SUM) will not be available at that point. `having` works on each group instead

Answer (score 0):

ok i know what is wrong 
i tried to access 'days' column before it is created with AS
that column will be available after line ->get() is executed.
So I changed order of these 2 lines :

```
->where('days', '=', $duration)
->get();
```

to

```
 ->get() 
 ->where('days', '=', $duration);
```

and now works :)

Comment: Using `->where()` after `->get()` means you are using `Illuminate\Collection`'s `->where()` method. It might not be the most performant approach, depending on size of the returning query. You can use `->having('days', '=', $duration)->get()` to access `days` in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your comment , I changed to way you described  and result is same and i think it's more proper.